# Why laravel can't find the css file?

Tags: laravel

I am using the following line to add the CSS file:

```
<link href="public/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And in source file I see it's showing:

```
<link href="public/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but somehow laravel can't find this CSS file!

Even I have used following line:

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('public/css/blog.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

and in source file it's showing:

```
 <link href="http://localhost:8000/public/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

But no luck!. it's saying:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Are you using `laravel-mix`?

Comment: @RuChernChong what do you mean by laravel-mix? I have 2 laravel installed in my localhost. 1) blog 2) laravel folder.

Comment: `Laravel Mix` is a compiler that helps you to compile your assets. Need to know if you are using that to give you a proper answer as things will work differently.

Comment: @RuChernChong I have got the solution. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reference the `public` folder explicitely, because this is already the web root (at least it is when the web server is configured correctly, also for security reasons). In other words, the browser only sees the content of the `public` directory - everything else is pulled in by the framework.

This means `<link href="css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">` should be enough. Alternatively, you can also go for `<link href="{{ asset('css/blog.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`.

Comment: Ah, that's was a easy solution, Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Try without public in your link:

```
<link href="/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and also check that **blog.css** exists in the folder: public/css

Your webserver should use Laravel's public folder as root folder.

Comment: Depending on where you deploy the application (i.e. a virtual path like `http://my.site.com/virtual/path`, this will not work, because the leading slash will always reference the domain root, i.e. `http://my.site.com/css/blog.css`.